# One milliamp current source for RTD

Tags: operational-amplifier, current-source, instrumentation-amplifier

I am trying to design a one milliamp current source (Howland current source) with a precision of +/- 1 uAmp.
The current source will be used to measure temperature with a 3 wires RTD sensor (H-T-01-12-00 from Honywell).

[image]

I did look at several voltage to current converter from Texas Instrument and Analog Devices using a pair of Op. Amp. and Instrumentation Op. Amp.

**Example   :**

INA128 & OPA177

INA114 & OPA131

LT6370 & LTC2057

I did some simulation with the tools provided by those manufacturers, but i was unable to get the required precisions, i was far from the expected result (I may did it in a wrong way).

I am not familiar with the behavior of those Op Amp. and Inst. Op Amp. and i do not have measurement tools to check.

Once the circuit board created, except the functionality, i won't be able to check the accuracy.

Could you please provide your remarks and suggestions on the components to be used, especially for U1, U2 and U3 (in DIP or SO package) or on the schematic itself ?

[image]

Thank you.

**Additional information**

I am targeting a 0.1°C precision.

According to the sensor's datasheet, i understood that the best precision i can expect is 0.3°C, but the sensor can be changed in future developments.

The circuit board is supplied with a single +5V voltage source.

Two current sources are used to supply the sensor.

An analog switch (MAX4662) is used to switch the current from one RTD termination to the other RTD termination.

The temperature is obtained by doing an average of two successive measures from two switched currents flow, 160 measures per sec.

The voltage accross the resistor RREF (1.1K) is VRREF = 2.2V (with 2mAmp current), used as Ref. for the DAC (LTC1864).

The temperature will vary from -30°C to +300°C (used in differents applications and environments).

Across the RTD, with a milliamp current, the voltage will vary from 0.088V to 0.212V  (according to the sensor's datasheet and the Callendar-Van Dusen function).

The output of the Inst. Op Amp U3 (Gain = 10) will vary from 0.88V to 2.12V

Comment: Shopping questions are off topic.

Comment: Watch out for the input common mode range of U1. Try your simulation with split supplies or using a 2.5V reference directly instead of using the IN-amp

Comment: Why use a Howland source?

Comment: Howland (and variations) is/are a very poor choice unless you're using AC excitation.

Comment: Thank you all for your feedback.
I choosed a Howland source for its simplicity and regarding my search, the current accuracy that can be obtained. But it seems that is not the best choice for this application.
Any suitable alternative or suggestion, meeting the requirements would be very helpful.

Comment: As well, 10uF C28 is a very bad idea. Read the op-amp datasheet.

Comment: It's going to be difficult enough to achieve 0.1% precision and very expensive if you want 0.1% accuracy so it's good you won't be worrying about that part. 0.1°C precision over -30°C to +300°C is also going to be very difficult. This is similar to the kind of equipment I worked on for years (well, two completely different families of devices; one from -200°C to +330°C direct contact simple probe, -200°C to +450°C direct contact specialized probe (or optical) and the other from 100°C to 1850°C direct contact and from 100°C to 4000°C optical with 0.2% *accuracy* at 1000°C. So I know.

Comment: @Jonk, thank you for sharing your experience on this matter. Without experiencing it, in some ways i felt the difficulty to have this level of precision.
The reason of this post is to have the view of expert matter on the design of one mAmp current source with 0.1/% precision for this kind of applications.
According to previous comments, Howland source is not suitable here but i still do not know why and which current source is appropriate.

Comment: @Spehro Pefhany, thank you for your inputs on the Howland sources and the C28. What kind of current source would you suggest ?

Comment: @topic There's not enough here for detailed thoughts, but at a guess I'd probably look at difference amplifiers in combination with opamps and voltage references within my size, price range, boutiqueness vs multi-sourceness, power and dissipation needs, etc. If you can afford to thermally stabilize important parts of the system, so much the better. Have you attempted to distribute your error budget, yet? At its most basic, it at least must divide into the precision available with a voltage reference and a current setting resistor. But it will be more than just that, in reality.